# Как сделать фильтрацию по нескольким значениям?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

Делал вот так, но так можно передать только одно значению, и по нему фильтровать. А я хочу что б можно было выбрать несколько категорий и по ним фильтровать. Category имеет тип данных enum

```
printingEdition = printingEdition.Where(x => x.Type == model.Category);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте список (массив) категорий и используйте метод `Contains`:

```
var models = new List<Category> { Category.A, Category.B };

printingEdition = printingEdition.Where(x => models.Contains(x.Type));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все отлично работает) Вы мне очень помогли)))